# What is a future-proof way for a web app to talk to a local program?

Tags: web-applications, websocket, cross-browser, mixed-content

I have a web application that is served via HTTPS. For some computationally-intensive work, this web app will offload work to the server. To do so, it will open a WebSocket connection to the server.

To allow offline use and long-running computations without putting too much load on the central server, I want to allow users to install a version of the server component locally, most likely in the form of a Docker container.

This would mean that the HTTPS web app would have to open a WebSocket to localhost – and it would have to be an insecure WebSocket, as I won't be able to ship a certificate for localhost, of course.

I initially thought that this wouldn't be possible, because at least in Chrome, HTTPS pages may not open WebSockets to non-secure endpoints:
[image: Mixed Content error]

However, there seems to be an exception for connections to localhost. Still, it seems a bit risky to assume that this won't change in the future.

Is there a more future-proof way to do this, like tunneling the communication through normal HTTP requests? I'm hoping for a solution that works in all modern browsers and requires no plugins or additional setup, only a native program to listen for a local connection in some way.

Comment: Why you are not using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to create an HTTPS certificate etc. on your distributed servers?

Comment: I won't be running distributed servers – users will run the server component locally, so I would need a certificate for localhost...

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do these calculations in a separate app rather than in a webWorker?  With the webWorker, it could still work offline, but you don't have any of the https communication issues.

Comment: Yes, performance: These computations would likely take too long in JavaScript. (Also, the external, native tool that does this is already completed.)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to expose a nonauthenticated websocket connection on localhost - another page can connect to localhost to get the local computer to perform some (potentially dangerous/insecure) task, even if you give the local computer a certificate.

I would recommend having the client you install on the machine generate a self-signed cert. I would also highly recommend that it use some kind of industry standard per-user authentication (perhaps with a simple HTTP Header Authorization field) that is *only* known to your webserver. If you can supply the key in the client download, that'd be ideal. Otherwise, the client can talk directly to your webserver to acquire this key (via the user logging in through the client). The webserver can then pass the key to the browser, then the browser can open a connection to localhost with the appropriate authorization.

Comment: I agree that there should be some kind of authentication to make sure only legitimate clients can submit tasks, although my central web server cannot play a role in that (it has no knowledge of the tasks the user wants to submit to his locally-running server component).

However, this doesn't really answer my question – namely what connection mechanism for this local connection is at least somewhat future-proof.

Comment: If your only concern is ensuring connectivity, I'd just use xhr-streaming instead of websockets (I assume you don't need to push that much data to the local server). Socket.io can already provide this functionality, or many other libraries. Websockets is likely overkill and still doesn't have perfect support across every browser.

Comment: I am forced to implement WebSocket support anyway (to comply with the specification to a protocol I am implementing), so using XHR will be *more* work than plain WebSockets. WebSocket support seems to be [widespread](http://caniuse.com/#search=WebSocket). Is there any reason to assume that HTTP-to-localhost has more future than WebSocket-to-localhost? (If so, I'd consider that a good reason to implement it.)

Comment: In your case I believe websockets will be totally fine, at least on modern browsers.

Comment: Unluckily, it seems like the localhost exception does not exist in Firefox or Edge.